# How do I repair my broken catalogue?

Tags: 12.10, package-management

I've run `sudo apt-get install -f` from which I received the error: (after typing 'y' to give it permission to install libreoffice-common)

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am running 12.10.

I also ran the commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then I tried

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-ogltrans
```

and received the error:

```
Package 'libreoffice-common' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-base-core : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-calc : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-draw : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-emailmerge : Depends: libreoffice-core but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-gnome : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-gtk : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-impress : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-math : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-pdfimport : Depends: libreoffice-core but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-presentation-minimizer : Depends: libreoffice-core but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-presenter-console : Depends: libreoffice-core but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-writer : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
 mythes-en-us : Depends: libreoffice-core but it is not going to be installed or
                         openoffice.org-core (>= 1.9) but it is not installable or
                         language-support-writing-en but it is not installable
 python-uno : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are experiencing this problem is a bug, and can be reported.

Try removing LibreOffice completely:

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-draw libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-presentation-minimizer libreoffice-presenter-console libreoffice-writer mythes-en-us python-uno openoffice.org-debian-menus libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-help-zh-cn
```

Then check that everything seems to be working normally:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Try installing SL (it's a small joke package that's harmless):

```
sudo apt-get install sl
```

This solution is based on [this discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/7307).

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:3.6.2~rc2) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-ogltrans : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution). -- is the error I receive after trying removing libreoffice common

Comment: @BrentonHorne: see my edit.

Comment: See my question edit (the resulting error was too long to fit in comments)

Comment: @BrentonHorne: see my edit again. If they are any packages that depend on `libreoffice-common`, just remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the offending .deb file first:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4_all.deb
```

Once that is done, update the list of available packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then proceed with running `apt-get -f install`, removing openoffice, etc.

Comment: Thanks, mate, I would try this if I could but Flimm solved it for me in chat.

Comment: if you have a solution, please post it as an answer to your own question and (after a bit) mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I'll let Flimm do so, I can't get credit for it, he can and he deserves it.